# How to connect old BX to AC in handy box

Tags: electrical, wiring

I need to extend an old 2 wire cloth wrapped 14ga BX cable. I got a steel handy box and a new 14/2 AC cable. The AC cable has a raw ground wire, the old BX cable doesn’t. I am not sure how to proceed. Did I get the right type of cable to use as extension?

[image: old wire]

[image: new wire]

Comment: That's not a ground wire, that's some BS strip of metal that lets you use the case as a ground *with the appropriate fittings* (supposed to bend that back and then put the fitting on). The question is if now that you've touched it, does code require you to pull the whole thing and have an actual ground wire.

Comment: "AC" is a type of cable, just like NM and UF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no ground wire on the box, the shield was probably used as safety ground. Confirm that, then if so connect new ground wire to the shield clamp.

Or install a GFCI, which provides life safety protection -- arguably better protection than safety ground, though that's certainly debatable -- between the box and the load.